# Adding JSON data to <ul> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Why am I not able to append data from json object to `<ul>` as `<li>` member?

```
<ul id="jsonData">
    <li></li>
</ul>  

<script>
 var employees = [
                  { "fName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }, 
                  { "fName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" }, 
                  { "fName":"Peter" , "lastName": "Jones" }
                 ];

  $.each(data.employees, function(key, val) {
    $('#jsonData').append(val.fName);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: do you want the names to come in a single `li` or in different `li` elements

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rf9ry/1/

Comment: or http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rf9ry/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any `data` object, you only have an `employees` array, so you need to do:

```
$.each(employees, function(key, val) {
    $('#jsonData').append("<li>" + val.fName + "</li>");
});
```

You also need to put your value inside `<li></li>` to append it as an HTML element.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c8JLV/)**

Comment: Thanks Felix, just can you please let me know when should we use the data object?

Answer (score 2):

You're attempting to add raw text to an HTML element. You need to add *html elements* to HTML elements. Try appending new `li` elements:

```
$.each(data.employees, function(key, val) {
  $('#jsonData').append('<li>' + val.fName + '</li>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#jsonData').append("<li>" + val.fName + "</li>);
```

Make sure you include the li tags so that it knows it's a list item.